# Postgres error when using this query:- postgres ERROR: could not identify an ordering operator for type record

Tags: sql, postgresql, operator-keyword

While running the following query Im getting this error

Message: Summary: ERROR: could not identify an ordering operator for type record Hint: Use an explicit ordering operator or modify the query. Details: com.amazon.redshift.util.RedshiftException: ERROR: could not identify an ordering operator for type record Hint: Use an explicit ordering operator or modify the query.

```
select
    i.spektr_date,
    i.campaign_id,
    avg(i.advertiser_id) as Advertiser_Id,
    max(i.ad_program_type) as ad_program_type,
    max(CAST(start_date AS DATE)) as Start_Date,
    max(CAST(end_date AS DATE)) as End_Date,
    max(cam.campaign_name) as Campaign_Name ,
    max(cam.status) as Campaign_Status, 
    max(cam.budget_currency_code) as Currency_Code,
    max(cam.daily_budget) as Budget,
    max(cam.smart_bidding_strategy) as Bidding_Strategy,
    max(cam.campaign_strategy) as Campaign_Strategy,
    sum(i.total_clicks) as Clicks,
    sum(i.total_impressions) as Impressions,
    sum(i.cpc*i.total_clicks) as Spend,
    sum(co.sale_price * co.sale_quantity) as Sales,
    sum(i.total_clicks)/sum(i.total_impressions) as CTR,
    (
        sum(co.sale_price * co.sale_quantity) / sum(i.cpc * i.total_clicks)
    ) as ROAS,
    (
        SUM(i.cpc * i.total_clicks) / SUM(co.sale_price * co.sale_quantity)
    ) as ACOS    
from
    spektr_ach.d_sp_ad_impressions i
    inner join spektr_ach.d_sp_ad_conversions co on i.advertiser_id = co.advertiser_id
    and i.campaign_id = co.campaign_id and i.spektr_date = co.spektr_date and i.ad_program_type = co.ad_program_type
    and i.traffic_attributes = co.traffic_attributes and i.cpc = co.cpc and i.ad_group_id = co.ad_group_id
    and i.ad_id = co.ad_id and i.session_id = co.session_id
    and i.customer_id = co.customer_id and i.marketplace_id = co.marketplace_id 
    inner join spektr_vulcan.o_campaigns cam on cam.campaign_id = co.campaign_id
    and cam.marketplace_id  = CAST(co.marketplace_id AS BIGINT) and cam.advertiser_id = co.advertiser_id
    where i.advertiser_id = 40420525505 and 
    i.traffic_attributes = 1
    and i.ad_program_type = 'SPONSORED_PRODUCTS'
    and i.total_clicks > 0
    and i.total_impressions > 0
    and i.spektr_date = date'2022-09-17' and i.spektr_date < date'2022-09-25'
    group by (i.spektr_date,
    i.campaign_id)
    order by(i.spektr_date,
    i.campaign_id);
```

Comment: Don't use ( and ) to create a record: order by i.spektr_date,
    i.campaign_id;

Comment: Remove the useless parentheses around the columns lists `group by i.spektr_date,
    i.campaign_id` and `order by i.spektr_date, i.campaign_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of the `ORDER BY` clause does not require parentheses, so PostgreSQL interprets the parentheses as record constructor. Omit them and the query will work as expected.